# How do I get the coordinate of a d3 line?

Tags: d3.js, coordinates

This seems like a very simple thing to do but I can't seem to figure it out. Say I have something like this:

```
svg.append('line')
  .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.value; });
```

(There's other stuff added but it's not necessary for this question)

So basically I set the lines' y1 value to the number taken from my data. But how can I take that value if I need it for something else like an if statement:

```
if ( (the value of y1) < 20 ) {
  Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out. Just write .attr with the value you defined like this:

```
if (d3.selectAll('line').attr('y1') > 20) {
  Do something
}
```

Comment: Since your getter will return the value of the **first** element only, you can use `select` instead of `selectAll`.